# How to upgrade magento ver 2.3.1 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

I'm in live, need to upgrade **Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.3**.
Please let me know, how to upgrade this version without any disturbance of my website.

Comment: First setup dev site copy of live site and then upgrade in Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.3.

Comment: @Priya, Let me know if my answer is helpful to you..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take your database & code backup first after that performs an update task.

Connect Your SSH and then go to your project root and run below command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
```

After that run

```
composer update
```

Once this command execution is completed run reindexer and cache command.

You can read detail info here: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/upgrade-magento-2.html

above steps working fine, otherwise follow these step by step (Manually):

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
cp composer.lock composer.lock.bak

Update in Composer.json -> 2.3.1 to 2.3.3
and changes in Composer.lock (2.3.1 -> 2.3.3)

php bin/magento maintenance:status

php bin/magento maintenance:enable


3) composer update

4) rm -rf var/ pub/static/ generated/*

5) php bin/magento setup:upgrade

6) php bin/magento setup:di:compile

6) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

8) php bin/magento cache:clean

9) php bin/magento cache:flush

10) php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Doing that directly on the production environment is extremely irresponsible.

Comment: Hi, when i run "setup:di:compile" i;m fashing error in  "Fatal error:  Declarati
on of (Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\
ContextInterface $context, Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart, array $shippingAddressesInput): void in /opt
/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php on line 2
0"

Comment: @Priya, Backup and delete the file /vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php

Comment: @Priya, This answer solved your problem?

Comment: Yeah @sanjay. Now it's working. In future if we face any problem in "SetShippingAddressOnCart.php" file. because it's deleted

Comment: @Priya, I don't think it makes any problem but still keep backup of that file and please accept my answer.

Comment: @sanjay, okay.., Thank you :)

Comment: @Priya, Welcome...! Happy coding...!

Comment: Hi, it sucessfully updated, but if i clear cache website goes "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: @Priya, Have you checked your server current CPU resource usages?

Comment: i had checked, it's not affected

Comment: @SanjayGohil, Is the Magento 2.3.4 upgrade covers the recent security patches too?

Answer (score 0):

```
- Download Magento latest version.
- copy composer.json file.
- and replace your composer.json file
- run composer update command
```

Comment: this is too complex, too many external operations, just run 2 composer commands...

Answer (score -1):

First backup from all of your data

1. Log in to the Magento Admin as administrator.
2. Navigate **System** >
   **Tools** > **Web Setup Wizard**.
3. Click **System** Configuration.

> Check your authentication keys in the provided fields if possible. Below is an example if you have already entered your keys.

4. Click **Save** Config.
5. Click **System Upgrade**.

> Then, you need Magento to check the readiness. If you want to add other components, simply click **Yes**.

6. After that, you are ready to upgrade to Magento 2.3. **Select versions to upgrade.**

**Or Try the CLI update process:**

1. On your terminal go into magento root folder.
2. Set magento 2 under maintenance mode.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

3. Search for the correct and latest magento 2 version

```
composer show magento/product-community-edition 2.3.* --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

4. Force your composer to use the latest version

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

5. Update your magento 2 installation

```
composer update
```

6. After successful update Upgrade magento and compile

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

7. Disable maintenance mode and you are ready to check the correct
   version

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```