# How to Update magento to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2

how to update magento 2 to magento 2.3.4

Comment: @DivyeshDusera, Please check my answer to this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298994/how-to-upgrade-magento-ver-2-3-1-to-2-3-3/298995#298995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable

php bin/magento deploy:mode:show

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

php composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.4 --no-update    

php composer update
```

***After Complete update just run below command***

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the composer.json file on root folder and change the version of magento in line 5:

```
"version": "2.3.4",
```

and under "require"

```
"require": {

"magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.4",
```

Now run:

```
composer update
```

Then run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And finally re-deploy the static files, which for me is this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.4 --no-update

then

> composer update
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to upgrade Magento 2 to Magento 2.3.4:

1. You **upgrade** directly from Magento 2 to Magento 2.3.4 **from the command line** if you installed the software by:

   - Downloading the metapackage using composer create-project.
   - Installing the compressed archive.

Then follow all the steps in the dev doc of Magento here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

2. You will **create a fresh new site** on Magento 2.3.4

After upgrading your Magento version or creating a fresh site on Magento 2.3.4, you have to **migrate all data** from your old store to the new one. However, if you don't have a background of technical skill, it's a complicated process because you move all the extensions and custom codes to be compatible with the Magento version 2.3.4. Therefore, you need to find Magento migration experts to help you perform the Magento migration.